# Can't get logbacks TimeBasedRollingPolicy running

Tags: java, logback, appender

I can't get this snippet running:

```
TimeBasedRollingPolicy<ILoggingEvent> rollingPolicy = new TimeBasedRollingPolicy<>();
rollingPolicy.setFileNamePattern("%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log");
rollingPolicy.start();
```

Whatever pattern I try, I keep getting

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FileNamePattern [%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log] does not contain a valid DateToken
    at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicyBase.start(TimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicyBase.java:46)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy.start(DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy.java:32)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy.start(TimeBasedRollingPolicy.java:90)
```

I've tried various examples from [the docs](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html), but what works in logback.xml doesn't seem to work in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this: https://github.com/tony19/logback-android/issues/51 you need a context and an appender. There is an example there.

Comment: In other words, call `rollingPolicy.start();` later